# Listening for audio.ended from an audio tag that was generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a page that generates dynamic audio elements and places them into the DOM. Here is a rough example of what my code is doing:

```
...
$("#container").html("<audio src='" + song.url + "'>");
```

Late in the code, I want to run some code when that audio element is finished playing it's file. But the `ended` vent seems to never get fired.

```
$("#container").on('ended', function() {
    console.log("this never gets called");
});
```

How can I catch the `ended` event (or any other event) from a dynamically generated audio tag?

edit: If I place the declaration of the event handler right after creating the audio element it works.

```
$("#container").html("<audio src='" + song.url + "'>");
$("#container audio").on('ended', function() {
    console.log("this does get called");
});
```

But this solution doesn't completely solve my problem because this `on` call needs to go in a Chrome Extension, which can't be recalled every time a new audio element is created.

Comment: In your edited version it works because the element is created when the bindings are done. Is that a solution that works for you?

Comment: @Krycke, actually no, because the `on` call actually needs to go inside a chrome extension, which has no way to be re-called each time a new audio element is created.

Answer (score 1):

Add the audio tag into the on call to allow event delegation.

```
$("#container").on('ended', 'audio', function() {
    console.log("this never gets called");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Is the audio playing?

Comment: Does #container exist when event binding is called? As the answer suggests, the dynamic element needs to be in the selector attribute on the 'on' function.

Comment: @Krycke, yes the container element is always on the page.

Comment: @user2182349, yes the audio plays fine

Comment: As Krycke suggested - could you show where the event assignment code is running relative to the rest of the page?